# Is there some Gui component I can use to allow users to create connection strings?

Tags: .net-2.0, connection-string

I have an client app which will use a connection string to get access to some data.  I need the administrators to be able to define the connection string that the clients will use.  I would like to give them a wizard similar to the one that is used to define a new ODBC data source, but don't want to write all of this functionality myself.  Is there some way that I can kick off this wizard, or is there some components that I can use to allow the administrator to define the connection string to hand out to clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is useful to anyone else, what I ended up doing is this:

Create a DbProviderFactory of the selected type (the selected types coming from DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses ())

then use this to create a DbConnectionStringBuilder.  This connection string builder can then be bound to a property grid, which will then expose different properties depending on the specific type of the DbConnectionStringBuilder it is given.

Its not exactly the wizard I was looking for, but it gave me a quick gui for the user to use.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this one [http://geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/archive/2005/06/29/45087.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20201020141816/http://www.geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/archive/2005/06/29/45087.aspx) also in discuss I could implement it for you)))

Comment: thanks, but I want something that will support different types of providers, not just sql server.